# Looking for a pv or dialog equivalent

Tags: zsh

I am working with network shell (nsh; bmc software) I believe it is based on zsh 4.3.4. I have written a script that connects to a list of variable solaris machines and runs numerous commands and then creates some local directories and files based off of those commands.

I am looking for a way to display the script's progress as it can take some time depending on the number of servers. I have been told by others I need to utilize pv or dialog. However, in nsh when attempting to run these commands I get "command not found." It could be a limitation of nsh as well.

As a simple example, I want to see the progress of the following:

```
for i in $(cat serverlist.txt)
do
nexec -i $i hostname >> hosts.txt
done
```

Of course my script is a lot more complex than this but I cannot seem to get it working correctly as pv and dialog are not available. Also I know I should be using read -r to truncate the file, but appears not to work correctly either.

Comment: External commands not available (if you have them installed) indicates something wrong with your PATH, rather than "limitation of the shell". (I don't know what nsh is, I'll just assume it's another roughly POSIX-compatible shell.)

Comment: Don't use a for loop here; `while IFS= read -r i; do nexec -i $i hostname; done < serverlist.txt > hosts.txt`.

Comment: This is not a problem with `nsh`; it's a problem of making sure `pv` or `dialog` is installed on the remote machine (which it appears not to be).

Comment: I guess its not installed in that case. I need another way of implementing this. Cannot simply install those. NSH is network shell.

Comment: Have a look at GNU Parallel. Pay attention to the `--bar` and `--progress` options.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is a project for work. Because of the restrictions and guidelines I am not allowed to install arbitrary software.

Comment: GNU Parallel is a *single* Perl script (~10000 lines).